# Как узнать , делает ли VeraCrypt корректное размонтирование диска при завершении работы lubuntu?

Tags: linux, шифрование, lubuntu, veracrypt

Внезапно пропали файлы сайта с зашифрованного диска, а именно их размер стал равен 0, причем не со всеми файлами такое. До обнаружения делал массовое редактирование в vscode и отправлял на сервер с помощью firefox, после чего выключал компьютер. Грешу на некорректное размонтирование диска, потому что до этого так стирались файлы на внешнем зашифрованном диске. Что искать в логах, не знаю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте в консоли ввести команду **dmesg | tail**, это отобразит последние записи журнала в система, ищите слова **“error”** или **“failed”**. Либо попробуйте изучить файлы **“syslog”** и **“messages”** в папке **/var/log**.

Если пропадают файлы то в большинстве случаев неправильное размонтирование диска. Попробуйте так же вручную размонтировать при помощи команды **veracrypt -d <Диск>** и изучить окно вывода и лог файлы.